# Accuracy result for imbalance dataset on Neural Network model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, unbalanced-classes

Im currently learning Classification Neural Network and Im working with imbalance dataset. I have 2 model with 2 different result and 4 type of classes.

The 1st model there are no sampling or dimensionality reduction made with about 12000 data.

1st Model
Model: NN
Accuracy : 91%

CM : [image: 1st Model]

The 2nd model, I perform ratio sampling, combine with RUS and SMOTE about total of 4000 (1000 data for each class). The majority sample about 8000 data has been reduced to 1000 data and minority data have been generated synthetically using SMOTE from 20 data to 1000 data.

2nd model
Model: NN
Accuracy: 89%

CM: [image]

The question is, does the 2nd model valid with so much majority features has been reduced and minority features generated synthetically?

Updated results with CM measurement.

[image]

Thanks,
K

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Are you sure that class imbalance is a problem for you? While it can appear to be a problem, it typically is not.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/247274)

Comment: Hi @Dave, I think it is, because the data is exponential. Ive updated the score for both model. Of course the 2nd model produce better results. That is the reason why I need help to determine either is reliable or not. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Don't use accuracy.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) Instead, [use probabilistic predictions and assess these using proper scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352). Why would "because the data is exponential" (what does this mean?) mean that "imbalance" is a problem?

Comment: Thank you for the Interesting idea @StephanKolassa, The meaning of exponential is the class is exponentially. For example. Class 1 have 10000 data, Class 2 Have 1000 data, Class 3 have 100 data and Class 4 have 10 data. This is Earthquake data, as we know high magnitude EQ (>8) are very low compare to other EQ. Thats the reason I balanced the data using RUS and SMOTE according from few published paper. In my understanding, both models are seems to be acceptable, the way we use the scale metrics come into purpose.

Comment: Per the links above, imbalance itself is usually not a problem, and resampling/SMOTE/whatever will not "solve" a non-problem. Statisticians are extremely puzzled why the Machine Learning/Data Science community keeps on thinking imbalance is problematic. I presume it's because of the reliance on [highly flawed evaluation metrics like accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352). Note that all the problems with accuracy also apply to precision, recall, F1 and other Fbeta scores.